# How do I correctly implement Redux Saga action dispatches?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm currently playing around with redux saga and I'm having troubles implementing it correctly. Let's say I have a reducer which keeps track of how many times the app is launched:

```
const startedAppState = createSlice({
  initialState,
  name: 'started-app',
  reducers: {
   incrementStartedAppCounter: (state: IUserAuthenticationState) => ({
      ...state,
      startedAppCounter: state.startedAppCounter + 1,
    }),
  },
});
```

Then I export the incrementStartedAppCounter action like this:

```
export const {
  incrementStartedAppCounter,
} = startedAppState.actions;
```

In my saga generator functions I call it the following way:

```
function* appStartOrSomething() {
  yield put(incrementStartedAppCounter());
}
```

Now this works, and the startedAppCounter is increased every time I launch the app. The issue is, that now my IDE complains (obviously) that `incrementStartedAppCounter()` in the sage expects a parameter (the state). If I dispatch the action like this `yield put(incrementStartedAppCounter)` the counter isn't increased - which I expected. How would I call this correctly? How would I implement it if I want to add another parameter, e.g. `yield put(setStartedAppCounter(5))`?

I feel like I went into the wrong direction there somewhere, can anybody help me out? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`yield put(incrementStartedAppCounter());` is the correct syntax. Action creators (like your increment function) are functions so that they can easily accept arguments like your second example. An action creator with no arguments must still be invoked to be dispatched (or put, in saga language).

`createSlice` from Redux Toolkit uses `createAction` and `createReducer` under the hood. You can read more about their action creators in their docs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction

Comment: Thanks for your help and taking the time to respond! Do you know how to type it correctly then so the IDE doesn't complain? Or is that something I just have to live with?